# Why does the default Stream.toList create an ArrayList?

Tags: java

I understand that the default implementation of Stream.toList will normally be overridden by an optimized implementation. However, the question remains.

The following code snippet is from Oracle OpenJDK for Java 22:

```
default List<T> toList() {
    return (List<T>) Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(this.toArray())));
}
```

If the returned List was meant to be modifiable, I would understand why the fixed-size List returned from Arrays.asList were wrapped with an ArrayList. However, it is unmodifiable.

What benefit does creating an ArrayList give here?

Comment: The constructor of `ArrayList` create a defensive copy.

Comment: Thanks! Did a search, but couldn't find the post referred to at first.